# Loss of Reputation more than Expected

Tags: bug, reputation

I noticed a loss of reputation in my profile today.
Under the reputation details, it says -6 reputation due to a user removed. But the loss of reputation appears to be 20.

I am pretty sure it was 2445 previously and now stands at 2425. 
Is there some reason or am I sensing it wrong?

**EDIT:**

This was before answering this question.

[Convert one dimensional array to two dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431030/convert-one-dimensional-array-to-two-dimensional-array/13431078#13431030)

Comment: You did enable "show removed posts" at the very bottom of that page?

Comment: Yeah I did. It There was none at least during the previous week.

Comment: Why the downvote??
Is there anything derogatory in it?